# Is this possible to change the font of whole application in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my app there is field change **font** Actually using that user can change the font of whole application.Is this possible actually if i have 100 field in my project (may be different different font size on every page ).How can user change the font size .so that it can reflect on whole application.As I goggled i found that there is functionality of zoom in and zoom out .It is not a good way to do that .? is there any way to change font of whole application?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SYX2s/show/

Comment: can you please exaplain how to do that .Please provide some code i need for whole aaplication not for single page .Give me some hints.

Comment: here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SYX2s/

Comment: is this valide on whole application

Comment: I need the same thing is there any way to zib my code and send you?

Comment: try it on your code. I never used Cordova before.

Comment: I am not using cordova .I am using jquery mobile..For compile the code only use cordova.actually i need some idea if you give me more help

Comment: use the code here to change font size http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SYX2s/ if it doesnt work, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a style dynamically and apply it to all elements within `body`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SYX2s/)**

```
 $('#select_font').on('change', function () {
    var style;
    var font = $(this).val();
    if ($('head').find('style.font').length === 0) {
        style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + ' !important; }</style>');
        $('head').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');
    } else {
        $('body *').removeClass('font');
        $('style.font').empty();
        style = '.font { font-size: ' + font + ' !important; }';
        $('style.font').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This article shows a nice way of doing it in CSS only.

http://joshnh.com/2011/07/26/are-you-using-ems-with-your-media-queries/

Key is to only using `em`, then you can switch font size globally by changing the base for `em`.

Comment: sorry i am beginner can you please provide with some example as sfiddle.@omar gave good example he didn't give any code.

Comment: @zeviorodrigues: Press Strg+U (in Firefox) in the example done by Omar

Comment: @zeviorodrigues no, the code here isn't for you, its for something else.